# Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0>

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

i'm using the Microsoft Graph Apps to retrieve or create OneDrive files. I made a POC last week and everything worked wonderfully.

Now i tried implementing the our App into an existing MVC website but i'm having weird messages that System.Threading.Tasks.Task cannot be found:

```
  at Microsoft.Graph.DriveRequest.<GetAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.Graph.DriveRequest.GetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.DriveRequest.GetAsync()
   at BizzMine.Data.Repositories.OnlineEditorRepo.OnlineEditorRepository.<RequestSuccess>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\Users\geertverthe\Documents\repos\bizzmine\BizzMine.Data.Repositories\OnlineEditorRepo\OnlineEditorRepository.cs:line 89
```

I suspect that there is some kind of problem with binding references to System.Threading.Tasks or even System.Web.Http but i am not sure.

This is the (simple) code i use:

```
 Drive myDrive = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Request().GetAsync();
```

And my GraphServiceClient is constructed like this:

```
_graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) => {
                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", _tokens.AccessToken);
                    await Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }));
```

.NET Framework version is 4.6.1

I do have the correct consent permissions and do have a valid access token.

Any idea on why i receive such kind of error and how i can fix this?

Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks for the reply but yes, it is the same framework version (4.6.1)

Comment: The `DelegateAuthenticationProvider` should be returning a Task. In the last line of your definition you have not returned it. Maybe try changing it from `await Task.FromResult<object>(null);` to `return (Task.FromResult(0));`

Comment: Nope, that gives the same result. I added the nuget package Microsoft.Graph into an existing repositories project together with other nuget packages. I think there must be a conflict somewhere with the System.Threading reference. I already tried bindingRedirection to fix it but no luck :(

Comment: What's the actual error message and type?

Comment: "Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0> Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync(System.Object, System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption)'."
on calling
var tempDir = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath("testing").Request().GetAsync(); (but actually on whatever call i make with the client)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lot of trying i managed to solve my issue. Since our solution and projects contain lots of nuget packages, one of them was system.net.http. Apparantly this came with a package NETStandard.Library.1.6.1. 
I found it strange to have a nuget package for system.net.http as this is just in the framework itself.

I could delete the system.net.http nuget packages after upgrading NETSTandard.Library.1.6.1 to the latest version.

Only changes i had to do after this was referencing the FRAMEWORK system.net.http in projects where it was missing and removing an obsolete binding redirect in some projects.

It works fine now :-)